# Output format datetime in yii

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, yii

I am new to yii framework.
Created a form (without using the built-in widgets), in the form of 2 fields.
time_start , time_end - type in the database DATETIME.
All the data in the database are recorded properly, but if you enter letters instead of them writes zeros.
I tried to add a rule in the model:

```
array ('time_start, time_end', 'type', 'type' => 'datetime', 'datetimeFormat' => 'Y-m-d H:i:s'),
```

It seems the format is the same as stored in the database but nothing happens.
In the controller after a method *safe ()*, wrote:

```
print_r ($ model-> getErrors ());
```

For example, introduce into the field :
  *2006-12-26 15:00:30*
Gets an array of:

```
Array ([time_start] => Array ([0] => Start must be datetime.) [Time_end] => Array ([0] => End must be datetime.))
```

and so tried different formats, but mistakes all the same.
Tell me, how can I do so that you can enter only in the format
(such as a database) and nothing else.
Thanks in advance.

---

**UPDATE **
In the "*views / site / index*":

```
  <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
        'dataProvider'=>$modeltask->search(),
        'itemView'=>'_viewtask',
    )); ?>
```

*viewtask*:

```
<div class="view">
    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('id')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->id), array('view', 'id'=>$data->id)); ?>
    <br />
    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('author_id')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::encode($data->author_id); ?>
    <br />
    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('performer_id')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::encode($data->performer_id); ?>
    <br />
    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('parent_task_id')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::encode($data->parent_task_id); ?>
    <br />
    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('project_id')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::encode($data->project_id); ?>
    <br />
    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('hours_plan')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::encode($data->hours_plan); ?>
    <br />
    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('title')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::encode($data->title); ?>
    <br />
<form action="http://testik.test/index.php?r=site/savec" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $data->id; ?>" name="id_task">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo Yii::app()->user->id ?>" name="id_user">
<input type="text" placeholder="Дата начала" name="time_start">
<input type="text" placeholder="Дата конца" name="time_end">
<input type="submit" value="Challenge accepted">
</form>
</div>
```

SiteController, method *actionIndex* and *actionSaveC* :

```
public function actionIndex()
    {       
    $modeltask=new Task('search');
    $modeltask->unsetAttributes();
    if(isset($_GET['Task']))
        $modeltask->attributes=$_GET['Task'];   
        $this->render('index', array(
            'modeltask'=>$modeltask,            
        ));
    }
    public function actionSaveC()
    {

$model = new Calendar;
$model->unsetAttributes();
if(!empty($_POST))
{
  $model->attributes = $_POST;
  $model->save();
print_r($model->getErrors());

  //$this->redirect(array('index'));
}
```

Model: One line added, nothing else has changed
Forgot to say that all created CRUD

Comment: Did you mean to have `'type'` then `'type' => 'datetime'` ?

Comment: You have to show us your controller, form model, and view for us to answer this question, though if you aren't using form widgets, you are likely loosing some functionality that you will have to write yourself.

Comment: @Pitchinnate , 

I was looking in the internet for what the rules need to add in the model.
To recorded only the desired format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your validation rule definition is wrong. If you want to only accept a correctly formatted date from the user, the rule should read

```
array ('time_start, time_end', 'date', 'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),
```

This sets up a [`CDateValidator`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDateValidator) with the correct date [format](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDateValidator#format), which you have to specify not using PHP `DateTime` conventions but with those of [`CDateTimeParser`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDateTimeParser).

Comment: Could you explain in more detail?

Comment: @S1ash: Explain what exactly?

Comment: Could you explain me how to do it in my example if you're not busy ?

Comment: you gave a rule in your question. replace it with the rule from this answer.

Comment: thank you))Еverything works)
Is it possible to create two rules for the format?
If one of them is true, then entered into database.

Comment: It is possible to create two or more rules for a given attribute in a model, but all must pass for the validation to pass.  If you want an 'Any' validator, you will have to create that yourself.